# Buttons of one particular view controller are not working

Tags: iphone, button, swift3, ios10, xcode8

On tapping one button of first view controller, I am navigating to second view controller with performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier is given in storyboard and working fine).Second view controller will be shown in Landscape mode.

In second view controller there is a mapView(google). below the map, there is one button; on top of the map there is one more button, but both the button actions are not working.

userInteractionEnabled, enabled , accessibility all are correct.

Action methods are also dragged from storyboards properly and have been properly connected.(Removed and even connected again also)

Still action methods are not getting called. Buttons are also not clickable there.

Couldn't find the reason. thanks for help.

Comment: Narayan could you please share your interface builder's view controller component hierarchy?

Comment: Or check cliptosubview property for that button.

Comment: cliptosubview is corect only...and buttons are on self.view .Still not clickable, cant find reason